# Getting attribute from intersecting polylines using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2

I've got 1 polyline feature class, which includes aprox. 500 lines with attributes (streets). 
To fill out certain documentation, I need to know which streets cross each of the streets. Those. I need the names of the streets crossing it to appear in the attributes of each line. Maybe a comma. Or if there is some other way.

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling that the Spatial Join technique described in this blog may provide you with an answer: https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/spatial-joins-hidden-trick-or-how-to-transfer-attribute-values-in-a-one-to-many-relationship/

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Understood. And first answer worked! Thanks!

Comment: It would be good if you could write up the steps you used as a self-answer to your own question.  That then benefits the next person with the same question.